# Reloading react native app in code

Tags: react-native

My use case is to reload the app on the click on a button so that a lot of properties can be redefined after that click.
Is there a way we can reload a react native app via code?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the equivalent of pressing the "Reload JS" Button in the Dev menu or do you mean calling something like `forceUpdate()` to reload the state/re-render?

Comment: The latter part. But this will only reload that particular component, right? What if I want to reload the whole app from some inner component?

Answer (score 2):

This is a huge workaround – but it is saving a lot of time and avoiding the frustration of not shaking correctly.

We just `throw 'Want to reload?` to prompt the error screen while in development, so we can hit refresh.

EDIT: If you want only to "reload" a button and its properties, you only need to rerender the parent component (if props are what you want to change), else, just change the state of the components, following normal react development.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using redux to easily manage states. This way, you can easily reload state.