# How to load the dev menu or reload react-native app in physical device programmaticaly

Tags: react-native

I'd like to load the dev menu or trigger a reload without having to shake my phone every time ... as it is kind of annoying.

I know it's possible since live reloading uses it. This is what i found in the [source: RCTDevMenu.h](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTDevMenu.h#L55)

`/**
 * Manually reload the application. Equivalent to calling [bridge reload]
 * directly, but can be called from JS.
 */
- (void)reload;`

Any idea how this (call reload from JS) can be achieved ?

Also, there are some similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234315/reloading-react-native-app-in-code).

Comment: you just need to long press menu button

Answer (score 1):

While this is being called from obj-c and not js, the following solved the problem for me on iOS with RN 0.43.0 using Cocoapods and can hopefully help other people who are embedding RN in an existing iOS app:

First make sure you have the 'DevSupport' subspec in your Podfile:

```
pod 'React', :path => './js/node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'DevSupport'
]
```

Then import React/RCTDevMenu.h which provides a category on RCTBridge that lets you access the RCTDevMenu.

```
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTDevMenu.h>

...

RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                          moduleProvider:nil
                                           launchOptions:nil];
[bridge.devMenu show];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';`
2. In your JS code where you want to perform the reload:
   `NativeModules.DevMenu.reload();`